# Oracle SQL Developer crashes when I try to type in the editor

Tags: java, linux, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, centos6

I have this problem that started as of late.

I have to work in an installation of Sql Developer 3.2.2 in a CentOS 6 server with JDK 1.6 and Oracle 11g Express and it runs quite well until i try to even type one single character to do anything in the code editor the program crashes and i get this error:

> Package:      jdk-1.6.0_45-fcs
>
> Latest Crash: mié 24 ene 2018 14:23:23
>
> Command:      /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java -Xmx640M -Xms128M
>   -Xverify:none -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Dsun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false -Dwindows.shell.font.languages= -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -Doracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp=false -Dide.AssertTracingDisabled=true -Doracle.ide.util.AddinPolicyUtils.OVERRIDE_FLAG=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.conf -Dsqldev.debug=false '-Dide.conf=\"/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf\"'
>   '-Dide.startingcwd=\"/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin\"' -classpath
>   ../../ide/lib/ide-boot.jar oracle.ide.boot.Launcher
>
> Reason:   Process /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/bin/java was killed by signal 6
>   (SIGABRT)
>
> Comment:      None
>
> Bug Reports:

what can I do? this is an old machine that i can't modify very much.

thanks beforehand

Comment: you could get a better machine?

Comment: Perhaps you could install one of older SQL Developer versions. How? When on download page, you'll see the "Troubleshooting - **Previous version**" link. Click it on every page to get to, well, as it says, its *previous version*. Which one to choose? I wouldn't know; 4.x, maybe?

Comment: @mike-tung No, i can't. This is a server with some sensitive data and can't replace it

Comment: @Littlefoot i thought about it already, but SQLDev 4 needs jdk 1.7 and we're using SQLDev 3.2.2 (which uses JDK 1.6) here and i'm not allowed to change its version :/

Comment: @Juan, version 3.2.2 is on JDK 1.6. Did you try it (download is here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-downloads-v322-2080107.html). **EDIT** Aha, didn't notice what you said, sorry. Huh, there are older versions, all down to 1.1, but if it has to be 3.2.2 - no idea, sorry.

Comment: @Littlefoot is alright. I was also wondering if it has to do with SQL Developer or is it something inside JDK 1.6's settings that makes it crash (hence the error report i've added)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your sqldev( oracle.com/sqldeveloper ) . The version you are running is ~2011/2012.  17.4 is the most current. If you can't install, feel free to pass my name to who controls your install. I'll gladly explain why to them
-kris